# Amazon Sagemaker - Unable to evaluate payload provided

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I built a Sagemaker endpoint that I am attempting to evoke using Lambda+API Gateway.  I'm getting the following error:

```
"An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from model with message \"unable to evaluate payload provided\"
```

I know why what it's complaining about, but I don't quite understand why it's occuring.  I have confirmed that the shape of the input data of my lambda function is the same as how I trained the model.  The following is my input payload in lambda:

```
X = pd.concat([X, rx_norm_dummies, urban_dummies], axis = 1)
payload = X.to_numpy()

response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                               ContentType='application/json',
                               Body=payload)
```

In the jupyter notebook where I created my endpoint/trained my model, I can also access the model using a numpy ndarray so I'm confused why I'm getting this error.

```
y = X[0:10]
result = linear_predictor.predict(y)
print(result)
```

Here is a modificaiton I make to serialization of the endpoint:

```
from sagemaker.predictor import csv_serializer, json_deserializer

    linear_predictor.content_type = 'text/csv'
    linear_predictor.serializer = csv_serializer
    linear_predictor.deserializer = json_deserializer
```

I'm new when it comes to Sagemaker/Lambda, so any help would be appreciated and I can send more code to add context if needed.  Tried various foramts and cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what algorithm you are trying to use in Sage but they have the quote below on their documentation. If your CSV has a header or if you don't specify the label_size a bad request (http status code 400) might be what you get because the model isn't compliant with what AWS expects to receive.

> Amazon SageMaker requires that a CSV file does not have a header record and that the target variable is in the first column. To run unsupervised learning algorithms that don't have a target, specify the number of label columns in the content type. For example, in this case 'content_type=text/csv;label_size=0'.

From: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/cdf-training.html#cdf-csv-format

Comment: I'm using LinearLearner.  So the text/csv I'm sending as input into the endpoint in Lambda is just a comma separated string basically.    I would've expected this to work and not sure why I'm getting a 400 error.

Note there are no labels here as I'm doing inference, not training.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're indicating to the SDK that you are passing JSON but `payload` in your code is actually a NumPy array.

I would suggest replacing `payload = X.to_numpy()` to `payload = X.to_json(orient='records')` or something similar to convert it to JSON first.

Comment: Is there a way to essentially check what the endpoint is looking for?  In my notebook it was trained on an Ndarray.

Comment: Like in cloudwatch or something @Noel Llevares